# How to query database for rows based on datetime field when I only have the year available to me?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I need to select all rows from a table based on year, however the only field I can query is a `DATETIME` field that could read e.g. `2020-05-08 14:30:34`.

How can I return entries based only off of the year?

```
$records = MedicalRecord::find()
    ->where(['dateCreated' => '2020'])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `YEAR()` function, try this:

```
$records = MedicalRecord::find()
    ->where(['YEAR(dateCreated)' => 2020])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `andWhere()` and compare against beginning and end of the year dates.

Probably worth keeping in mind that this would be the equivalent of comparing dates as strings, but since the ordering is YY-mm-dd, it works.

```
$records = MedicalRecord::find()
    ->where(['>=', 'dateCreated', '2020-01-01 00:00:00'])
    ->andWhere(['<', 'dateCreated', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'])
    ->all();
```

This way `yii` generates the code that runs against the database

If you can guarantee that you will be only running your application against a database engine that supports the `YEAR()` function, then Serghei's answer is probably best. But if you wanted to migrate to PostgreSql, Oracle... It would stop working.

Comment: In case of MySQL it will be [compared as number](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-date.html). Also your solution might be faster then the one in accepted answer because it can use standard indexes. The other one might require to set up index with functional key part for `YEAR`.